# How can you set a UILabel's height to exactly match its font size?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I've got a UI design spec to follow where the spacing between text is precisely specified i.e. here's a spec for vertical spacing in a table view cell:

[image]

The problem when using a storyboard and constraints is that when you place a UILabel in the storyboard its height is larger then its contained font size (so you can't for example set a vertical constraint of 6 between the two line in the spec for example, as that would set the UILabels 6 points apart, not the contained text 6 apart).

Here's a diagram to make it clear what I mean:

[image]

Here the constraint is 6px. But I want to be able to set the distance between the bottom of the text of Label1 and the top of the text of label 2 to be 6.
By setting a vertical constraint of 6 between the labels, the distance between the text within those labels is greater than 6.

I attempted to solve this by using a custom label:

```
@IBDesignable
class NoPaddingLabel: UILabel {
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't adjust the height of the UILabel in the storyboard despite the @IBDesignable - for example if you drag and drop a UILabel then by default its System font size 17, with a height of 21. If its type is changed from UILabel to NoPaddingLabel its height is still 21.
If constraints are then added there's tones of errors regarding vertical compression and vertical hugging priorities conflicts.

So, is there a way to calculate the height of the UILabel in the storyboard to correspond to the height of its font so that its easier to set exact vertical constraints between text? -

Whats the solution to set exact constraint distances between text, rather than between labels in a storyboard?

Comment: Hello! First of all, a font size of value 17 doesn't mean that the label height should be 17 equivalently. The height depends on the font typography and is generally greater than the font-size. Now, coming back to your question to set two labels having different font sizes to be apart by a fixed constant say 6, then it can be easily achieved by setting a vertical spacing constraint of 6 px and no need to give any height constraints on the two labels. Let it calculate the height automatically of the labels based on font and keep a fixed spacing of 6 as per the constraint added.

Comment: @Jen Jose " it can be easily achieved by setting a vertical spacing constraint of 6 px" but it can't and  that is my point and my question - setting 6px distance between two labels is not the same as setting 6px distance between the text within those labels. I have added a new diagram to the question to make this clear.